# What does "Splats" mean in the CoffeeScript tutorial?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Looking at this CoffeeScript tutorial : http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

I don't quite see what the Splats is for. What is this construction? Where does it come from (historically)

Comment: And as usual, you should also know how it can be implemented in vanilla Js: `arguments` + `call`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380315/splat-operators-in-javascript-equivalent-to-args-and-kwargs-in-python

Comment: I like to think of it as a parameter that gets "splatted" (like paint) into an indefinite continuum

Comment: For anyone Python-inclined: this is your `*args` in `def foo(*args):`.

Comment: Terminology note: ES6 adopted similar but prefix syntax. In ES6 receiving `, ...args` is named [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and expanding `...args` into a function call / array / object literal is named [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

The term "splat operator" comes from Ruby, where the `*` character (sometimes called the "splat"—see [the Jargon File entry](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/splat.html)) is used to indicate that an entry in an argument list should "soak up" a list of arguments.

CoffeeScript adopted Ruby-style splats very early on (see [issue 16](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/16)), but at Douglas Crockford's suggestion, the syntax was changed from `*x` to `x...` a couple of weeks later (see [issue 45](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/45)). Nevertheless, CoffeeScripters still refer to the syntax as the "splat" or "splat operator."

As to what they actually do, splats slice the `arguments` object in such a way that the splatted argument becomes an array of all "extra" arguments. The most trivial example is

```
(args...) ->
```

In this case, `args` will simply be an array copy of `arguments`. Splatted arguments can come either before, after, or between standard arguments:

```
(first, rest...) ->
(rest..., last) ->
(first, rest..., last) ->
```

In the first two cases, if the function receives 0-1 arguments, `rest` will be an empty array. In the last case, the function needs to receive more than 2 arguments for `rest` to be non-empty.

Since JavaScript doesn't allow multiple signatures for functions with the same name (the way C and Java do), splats are a huge time-saver for dealing with varying numbers of arguments.

Comment: Similar to the C# [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword.

Comment: When would I ever need to use this?

Comment: when you are unsure of the number of params that you want to accept .

Comment: Technically known as a [variadic function] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), or a function of indefinite "arity". Most languages use an ellipses form of some sort to indicate variable arguments.

Comment: @JeffScottWard a perfect example is console.log, it accepts any number of arguments. `console.log('this:',variable,'should be replaced with', another_variable);`

Answer (score 13):

if you know python, `args...` roughly similar to `*args`, as it allows you to treat function parameters as list

for example:

```
concat = (args...) -> args.join(', ')
concat('hello', 'world') == 'hello, world'
concat('ready', 'set', 'go!') == 'ready, set, go!'
```

it works in assginments, too:

```
[first, rest...] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
first == 1
rest == [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

Splats is the term for the use of the `...` operator for var-args (functions that take a variable number of arguments).

Comment: See also: Python's *args and **kwargs, and ActionScript 3's rest parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a syntactic sugar for javascript's arguments object.

The idea may come form ruby's [splat operator `*`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html).

Comment: technically, it's a little bit more, as it can used left-hand-sided in assignments, and can be combined with named arguments: in `(x, rest...) ->`, `rest` wont contain `x`, `arguments` does.