# Optional arguments in Coffeescript functions

Tags: function, coffeescript

I have been seeing functions with signatures

`some_fn arg1, arg2, [optional], cb`

How is this done?

Comment: Where have you seen this? Usually, the optional arguments go at the very end.

Comment: In this example, which parameters should be optional, and which ones should be mandatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does that sort of thing all the time, [`on` for example](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> **.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )**

The way it works is that the inner optional arguments and the final argument have different types so the function can parse [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) by hand using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) (or similar but looser checks like the various [`is*` functions in Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#isArray)) to figure out how it was called. If there are multiple things in the possible argument list that are the same type then you'd throw a length check into the mix to try and figure out what the intent is.

For example:

```
f = () ->
    args = Array::slice.apply(arguments)
    if(typeof args[0] == 'function')
        args[0]()
    else
        console.log("#{args[0]} is not a function")

f(1, 2, 3)
f(-> console.log('pancakes'))
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/c6UwC/

A more CoffeeScript-ish version would use `...` instead of dealing with `arguments` directly:

```
f = (args...) ->
    if(typeof args[0] == 'function')
        args[0]()
    else
        console.log("#{args[0]} is not a function")
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gPmJZ/

Comment: aww interesting use of the splat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201657/what-does-splats-mean-in-the-coffeescript-tutorial

Comment: @Alexis: As far as why this argument form is used, putting an anonymous function in the middle of an argument list is pretty ugly and visually confusing (yes `setTimeout` and `setInterval` do it but those signatures are (IMO) mistakes and lead to lots of nasty looking code).