# Splat operators in JavaScript, equivalent to *args and **kwargs in Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I use Python a lot, and I am just quickly learning JavaScript right now (or should I say re-learning). So, I wanted to ask, what is the equivalent of `*args` and `**kwargs` in JavaScript?

Comment: [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) has splats

Comment: Try calling `function.apply(obj, [args])`. Every function object has an `apply()` method that calls the function with a context (ie `obj`) and an array of arguments.

Comment: Why not just passing in a key-value pair object? You can do `if (key in obj)` in javascript as if you do `if arg in kwargs` in python. Then if it returns true, you can just get value with `obj[key]`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35680335

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The closest idiom for `*args` would be

```
function func (a, b /*, *args*/) {
    var star_args = Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments, func.length);
    /* now star_args[0] is the first undeclared argument */
}
```

taking advantage of the fact that `Function.length` is the number of arguments given in the function definition.

You could package this up in a little helper routine like

```
function get_star_args (func, args) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call (args, func.length);
}
```

and then do

```
function func (a, b /*, *args*/) {
    var star_args = get_star_args (func, arguments);
    /* now star_args[0] is the first undeclared argument */
}
```

If you're in the mood for syntactic sugar, write a function which transforms one function into another one which is called with required and optional arguments, and passes the required arguments along, with any additional optional arguments as an array in final position:

```
function argsify(fn){
    return function(){
        var args_in   = Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments); //args called with
        var required  = args_in.slice (0,fn.length-1);     //take first n   
        var optional  = args_in.slice (fn.length-1);       //take remaining optional
        var args_out  = required;                          //args to call with
        args_out.push (optional);                          //with optionals as array
        return fn.apply (0, args_out);
    };
}
```

Use this as follows:

```
// original function
function myfunc (a, b, star_args) {
     console.log (a, b, star_args[0]); // will display 1, 2, 3
}

// argsify it
var argsified_myfunc = argsify (myfunc);

// call argsified function
argsified_myfunc (1, 2, 3);
```

Then again, you could just skip all this mumbo jumbo if you are willing to ask the caller to pass the optional arguments as an array to start with:

```
myfunc (1, 2, [3]);
```

There is really no analogous solution for `**kwargs`, since JS has no keyword arguments. Instead, just ask the caller to pass the optional arguments in as an object:

```
function myfunc (a, b, starstar_kwargs) {
    console.log (a, b, starstar_kwargs.x);
}

myfunc (1, 2, {x:3});
```

### ES6 Update

For completeness, let me add that ES6 solves this problem with the rest parameter feature. See [Javascript - '...' meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421404/javascript-meaning/28421548)

Comment: Would it be easier for me to dive straight into CoffeeScript instead of spending time with javascript?

Comment: That reminds of the time someone asked me if they should dive straight into FORTRAN instead of spending time with 7090 assembler. Sure, CoffeeScript is a good approach. Or TypeScript, or Traceur, which gives you a migration path to ECMAScript 6 (where the syntax, by the way, is `function (a, ...optionals)`). Any of these also give you default argument values, without you needing to hack that together using POJS using some of the same ideas as in my answer.

Comment: ES6 link 404 not found

Answer (score 71):

ES6 added a spread operator to JavaScript.

```
function choose(choice, ...availableChoices) {
    return availableChoices[choice];
}

choose(2, "one", "two", "three", "four");
// returns "three"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is only analogous to `*args`, and cannot unpack objects like `**kwargs`

Comment: A similar way to to unpack objects would be `function choose({choice, ...availableChoices}) {/*...*/}`. Usage would be: `choose({choice: 'a', a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});`

Comment: That comment really belongs in the answer

Comment: Could someone please point to a resource that goes into detail on the comment of @eskimwier ?

Comment: @Haniver, not sure of a resource but I made a quick post on my site about it: https://mike.distro.work/using-the-javascript-object-rest-operator-in-function-parameters

Answer (score 18):

I found a good solution here:
http://readystate4.com/2008/08/17/javascript-argument-unpacking-converting-an-array-into-a-list-of-arguments/

Basically, use `function.apply(obj, [args])` instead of `function.call`. apply takes an array as the 2nd arg and 'splats' it for you.

Comment: This worked for me when I wanted to pass a function and the arguments to a callback.

Comment: unfortanely bad url:(

Answer (score 9):

The nearest equivalent is the [`arguments` pseudo-array](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/).

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript 6 will have [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) which do the same thing as the splat operator.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might be slightly lost about *args and **kwargs magic variables read http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html

Summary:
*args and **kwargs are just conventional ways of writing the magic variables. You could just say * and ** or *var and **vars. That said lets talk about the JavaScript equivalent in 2019.

*args in python represents a JavaScript Array e.g. ["one", "two", "three"] to pass that into a python function you would just define the function as def function_name(*args): meaning this function accepts "arrays" or "list if you wish" to call that you would simply use function function_name(["one", "two", "three"]):

same thing in JavaScript can be done by using :

```
function func(x,y,z){
  ...
}
let args = ["one", "two", "three"];

func(...args)

**or more dynamically as**

 function func(inputs){

   for(index of inputs){

      console.log(inputs[index]);
   }
}
let args = ["one", "two", "three"];

func(args)
```

Have a look at https://codeburst.io/a-simple-guide-to-destructuring-and-es6-spread-operator-e02212af5831

**kwargs on the other hand represent just an array of key value pairs(objects) that's it. Thus
**kwargs e.g is [{"length": 1, "height": 2}, {"length":3, "height": 4}]

in python to define a function accepting array of objects you just say def function_name(**kwargs): then to call that you can do function_name( [{"length": 1, "height": 2}, {"length":3, "height": 4}]):

similarly in JS

```
const kwargs = [{"length": 1, "height": 2}, {"length":3, "height": 4}]

function func(obj1, obj2){
  ...
}

func(...kwargs);

**or more dynamically as:**

const kwargs = [{"length": 1, "height": 2}, {"length":3, "height": 4}]

function func(obj){
  for(const [key, value] in Object.entries(obj)){
    console.log(key, ": ", value)
 }

func(kwargs);
```

Comment: it's impossible to make a variable called `**kwargs` in javascript

Comment: Thanks Jake will rectify that

Answer (score 0):

use array to pass arugment dynamic (ES6), in javascript I think this is the splat operators in javascript equivalent to args and kwargs in python

```js
let argus = [1, 'Jone Doe'];
function message(userId, name){
  console.log(userId, name);
}
message(...argus );
```