# What's the JavaScript equivalent of Ruby's splat operator?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-harmony

In Ruby, you can use the splat (`*`) operator to capture a variable number of arguments to a function, or to send the contents of an array to a function as an argument, like so:

```
def example(arg1, *more_args)
  puts "Argument 1: #{arg1.inspect}"
  puts "Other arguments: #{more_args.inspect}"
end

test_args = [1, 2, 3]

example(*test_args)
```

Output:

```
Argument 1: 1
Other arguments: [2, 3]
```

What's the equivalent of this in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splat operators in JavaScript, equivalent to \*args and \*\*kwargs in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380315/splat-operators-in-javascript-equivalent-to-args-and-kwargs-in-python): Python splats are analogous on definition and call.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In older versions of JavaScript (ECMAScript 5), no exact equivalent to this exists. In modern browsers which support ECMAscript 6 though, there is something very similar denoted by three periods (`...`).

When used in function calls and array declarations this triple-dot syntax is known as the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). When used in a function definition, it is called [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/rest_parameters?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/JavaScript/Reference/rest_parameters).

Example:

```js
function example(arg1, ...more_args) { // Rest parameters
  console.log("Argument 1: ", arg1)
  console.log("Other arguments: ", more_args)
}

test_args = [1, 2, 3]

example(...test_args) // Spread operator
```

Output:

```
Argument 1:  1
Other arguments:  [2, 3]
```

The spread operator and rest parameters are available in the latest versions of all major browsers (except Internet Explorer) and the latest Node.js LTS release.

Full compatibility tables: [Spread operator](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator), [Rest parameters](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-rest_parameters)

Comment: ES6's "spread" operator is ruby splat's "split" operation, and ES6's "rest" parameter is like ruby splat's "slurp/collect" operation. See: http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html

Answer (score 5):

The first use can be accomplished (messily) using `Array.slice(arguments)`.

The second can be accomplished by using the `.apply()` method of your function.