# nodejs equivalent of python parameters star and double star

Tags: python, node.js

Just trying to transfer some things that I learned in Python to NodeJs.
Is there an equivalent in NodeJs to star and double star argument which are used in Python in the following function definitions?

```
def foo(self, *a, **kw):
```

It's useful for templates rendering notably.
I did check google before asking!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It called "splat" and "splatsplat". Same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380315/splat-operators-in-javascript-equivalent-to-args-and-kwargs-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splat operators in JavaScript, equivalent to \*args and \*\*kwargs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380315/splat-operators-in-javascript-equivalent-to-args-and-kwargs-in-python)