# Angular / Typescript method with optional args

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a method:

```
 mymethod(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4): void {
   // do something
 }
```

My question is ... how can I set it so that any arg is optional?

Comment: `arg1?, arg2?, arg3?, arg4?` although that will not enable you to (easily) pass only the fourth one, for example.

Comment: I suggest to use an object parameter so that you can easily detect if, for example, arg2 is defined or not

Comment: You can use object as parameters `myMethod(myArgs:{arg1?: any, arg2?:any ....}){if(myArgs.arg1){// Do magic with arg1}}`

Comment: So if I want to just pass the 4th one do I do this: mymethod(null, null,null,'something here') ? Would that be valid?

Comment: @teumec valid but not best approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this happen you can use a object parameter like written in the comments. Below you can find a working code snippet:

```
interface ITest {
    arg1?: string;
    arg2?: string;
    arg3?: string;
    arg4?: string;
}

function callTest(args: ITest): void {
    console.log(args);
    if(args.arg2) {
        console.log('arg2 is set')
    }
}

const obj: ITest = {
    arg1 : 't1'
};

callTest(obj);
callTest({ arg1: '1', arg2: '2'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```js
const myMethod = ({arg1, arg2, arg3}) => {
  console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3);
};
myMethod({arg1: 1, arg3: 255})
```

This way you can add as many arguments as you want.

If you're looking for something like kwargs in python, check [Splat operators in JavaScript, equivalent to *args and **kwargs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380315/splat-operators-in-javascript-equivalent-to-args-and-kwargs-in-python)