# Recursive JavaScript value not coming back

Tags: javascript, recursion, coffeescript

I'm attempting to write a scheduling application which takes in course information and creates all possible schedules.  I have never written a recursive function in javascript before, but I'm not sure why it would be different from any other language.

The values appear to be properly added to the arrays while in the recursive method, but once execution returns to the non-recursive function the values are apparently missing.

Below are the functions in question (written in coffee script), and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zposten/9r9r4ymy/2/) is a fiddle with my current functionality.

Can someone please tell me why both of the arrays in `schedules` that is returned are empty?

```
combine: ->
    schedules = []
    @recursiveCombine(@courses, [], schedules)
    return schedules

recursiveCombine: (courses, chosenSections, schedules) ->
    if chosenSections.length is Object.keys(courses).length
        console.log 'pushing schedule: '
        for section in chosenSections
            console.log '\t' + section.courseName + ' ' + section.number

        schedules.push chosenSections
        return

    next = chosenSections.length
    course = courses[next]
    for section in course.sections
        if not @overlap(section, chosenSections)
            chosenSections.push section
            @recursiveCombine(courses, chosenSections, schedules)
            chosenSections.pop()
```

Comment: What is `@courses`? You're doing both `Object.keys(courses)` and `courses[chosenSections.length]`, the first suggests that `courses` is an object but the second suggests that it is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
schedules.push chosenSections
```

is adding the array `chosenSections` *by reference* to your final array. When you later modify this array with `chosenSections.pop()`, the things you expect to be in `schedules` effectively "disappear". You need to copy the `chosenSections` array into `schedules`. Judging by the rest of your code you probably simply meant to flatten it:

```
if chosenSections.length is Object.keys(courses).length
    console.log 'pushing schedule: '
    for section in chosenSections
        console.log '\t' + section.courseName + ' ' + section.number

        #here we are copying a reference to each item inside chosenSections
        schedules.push section
    return
```

A more CoffeeScript-y way to do this is with the [splat operator (`...`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201657/what-does-splats-mean-in-the-coffeescript-tutorial). Removing the logging, it looks like this:

```
if chosenSections.length is Object.keys(courses).length
    schedules.push chosenSections...
    return
```

Comment: My apologies.  My intention was to not return anything in the first half of the recursive function either because I'm modifying the contents of the passed in array.  I have tried returning the variable (and thus the typo you point out) but it made no difference.  I have updated the code and the fiddle to reflect this.

Comment: I see. Let me take another look then.

Comment: Ok I believe I've found the issue

Comment: That makes a great deal of sense, thank you so much!